# Position not implemented for music type in pygame

Tags: python, audio, pygame, runtime-error

I seem to find this error when running some code:

error: Position not implemented for music type

The aim of the code is to play a sound from a certain point and end at a certain point in the following function:

> def play(start,end):
>
> ```
>    print(start)
>
>    pygame.mixer.music.play(0,start)
>
>    begin=time.clock()
>
>    finish=time.clock()
>
>    while finish-begin<end:
>         finish=time.clock()
>
>    pygame.mixer.music.stop()
>
>    pygame.mixer.music.rewind()
> ```

It can also be noted that the function works fine once but on the second time retrieves the error.

Comment: It would be better to have the complete error traceback.

Answer (score 2):

The function `pygame.mixer.music.play` will only accept a start time parameter if the music file is of type mp3, ogg or mod.  This is due to a limitation in the SDL library as documented at https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_mixer/docs/SDL_mixer.html#SEC_Top

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working snippet tested on both Windows 10 and Android.

```
import pygame.mixer

#SOUND_FILE = 'c:/temp/JMJ.mp3'
SOUND_FILE = '/storage/emulated/0/music/JMJ.mp3'

pygame.mixer.pre_init(44100, -16, 2, 2048)
pygame.mixer.init()

pygame.mixer.music.load(SOUND_FILE)
pygame.mixer.music.play(loops=0, start=1626) # 1626 seconds from beginning

while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy():
    pygame.event.wait()
```

Comment: Hi there. I'm quite curious: what do you use to be able to write games in Python and Pygame for Android? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why not use

```
pygame.mixer.music.set_pos(pos)
```

to set the position you want to start at.  You could then run

```
pygame.mixer.music.get_pos()
```

in a loop until you reach the desired point in the music to stop it.  Then you can repeat the music every time you reach a certain point etc.  If this isn't what you're looking for, please comment below.  Good luck!